# 1 + 1 = 0 ? What am I missing! Have been coding for too long today? :(

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, console

Using VS2008 C++, console application (empty, made from scratch), placing this in the code :

```
printf("\n\n%d + %d = %d !!!\n\n",(unsigned __int32)(19L / 17L),((19L % 17L) == 0L)?0L:1L,(unsigned __int32)(19L / 17L) + ((19L % 17L) == 0L)?0L:1L);
```

And when I run the program, I get :

```
1 + 1 = 0 !!!
```

What am I missing?????? `:'~(`

Comment: Kinda looks like the last `0L:1L` should be `1L:0L`.

Comment: well, I want an in-place implementation of ceil() without actually having to use a function... it should give 2 instead of 0

Comment: sorry, they just need to be in parenthesis (both parts separately, that is) printf("\n\n%d + %d = %d !!!\n\n",(unsigned __int32)(19L / 17L),((19L % 17L) == 0L)?0L:1L,((unsigned __int32)(19L / 17L)) + (((19L % 17L) == 0L)?0L:1L));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("\n\n%d + %d = %d !!!\n\n",(unsigned __int32)(19L / 17L),((19L % 17L) == 0L)?0L:1L,((unsigned __int32)(19L / 17L)) + (((19L % 17L) == 0L)?0L:1L));
```

it seems to be a simple issue of operator precedence. I definitely have been programming for too long today :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 'precedence'.  In the last argument to printf(), the addition is higher precedence than the conditional.  The sum is evaluated as

```
(__int32)1 + (2L == 0)    which is 1 + 0, or 1 (which is then promoted to long)
```

Therefore the conditional resolves to

```
1L ? 0L : 1L
```

which is 0L since the 'condition' is non-false (non-zero).